# Rejected edit followed by almost the same edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

The problem is with [my suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6029612).
I don't understand the mistakes I made as the following edit is almost the same as my edit.

I would like to know how to proceed in such cases and make better suggestions.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The reviewer chose to *Reject and Edit* option, discarding your suggested edit and then 'improved' the post directly. Using this option is a bit like a veto vote; just the one reviewer caused your edit to be rejected.

I'm actually quite puzzled the reviewer did this, as their edit is **not** better than yours. Your edit was substantially better, and I have applied it manually. I also left a comment for the reviewer asking why they chose this option.

Please do disregard the (canned) rejection message on that suggested edit, and please do carry on making edit suggestions like these!

Comment: Thank you! I believe everybody involved learned something.

Comment: The irony is that I'd come close to arguing that the (elected by all) formatting in this case *makes the question worse* as while it looks superficially organized only relatively unimportant prefixes actually show now, and it's necessary to use the scroll tool to see the parts of the messages which actually matter.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: feel free to shorten the paths in the error output if you feel the lines are too long, provided you don't lose any meaning.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Python tracebacks put the code on a separate line from the location, for exactly these scrolling issues.

Comment: That does sound better - and my point is that the original effectively did so as well.  The problem with cutting out part of the lines is that doing so (in addition to being labor intensive) is a slippery slope of judgement calls.  Most of the prefix is *probably* unimportant, but how much?  There's a big difference between seeing all the information on the screen, vs. having the information one person believed unimportant *removed* to emphasize what they thought was important - such beliefs can turn out to be mistaken.

Comment: I'm not pushing to revert this (the question is not one I find interesting anyway) but it does make an extreme example of a sometimes debatable assumption that reformatting is better.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: note that the issue here was not the formatting of the error message, that was the *only* thing the reviewer had re-applied. The formatting we are addressing here was for the spelling and grammar of the *rest* of the post.

Comment: But this happens too often ! Many user that reviews edits make this ! 
There should be a way to flag this behaviour.

Comment: @Dwhitz: there already is a way to flag this behaviour: if you see that someone has a *pattern* of such reject-and-edit reviews where the original suggested edit should not have been rejected, flag a post they edited this way for moderator attention. Describe, in detail, what you observed and why you are flagging.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not someone specifically but many reviewers reject edits for approve theirs. This happens often to me, but also for many others users which can edits but have less than 2k reputation.
It could be helpful say something like "hey my edits was ok, don't do edits and approves mine edit!"

Comment: @Dwhitz: If you have *proof* (numbers, not just your say-so), you could create a new Meta post to discuss this. There is no specific gain for a reviewer to do this (no points are awarded as a result of their edit getting in instead of yours), and with no incentive I don't see why this would be common. Take into account that just because you feel your edit is Ok, that the edit actually was Ok, though. Please bring *objective proof*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes of course, i have more 40 edits rejected and about half of that are for reviewers which rejects and edits. 
It could be because i'm bad at edit questions, or maybe not. The point is, could be helpful for the user, stop the reviewer ?

Comment: @Dwhitz: no, then review would be pointless. Why have reviews at all if you could just override them?

Comment: @Dwhitz: now, the *author of the post* you edited can still decide to accept the edit after the fact (provided there were no other edits since): [Could authors overturn recent community review decisions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/178340)

Comment: @Dwhitz: I agree that [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16148314) did not deserve to be rejected like that; your edit was Ok enough (but do look at the [edit made by PVitt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44019245/revisions)).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, i agree with you. But in the link you mentioned the "problem" isn't PVitt but hassan. He could  approve my edit and then add his improvements? Like PVitt did with hassan.

Comment: @Dwhitz: I'm pointing out other things you could have edited; hassan did not make a suggested edit, PVitt came later and made more edits *you could have made too*.

Comment: @Dwhitz: *Generally* I'd have expected them to accept and edit. I don't see any evidence that this reviewer is in the habit of using reject-and-edit, it could have been a one-off error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But how i said some comments ago, i'm not focusing on a user but on the behaviour of the reviewer. This errors happens often or not often but happens. I wanna know if it should be marked in some way or is only a my opinion.

Comment: @Dwhitz: I already told you when it should be flagged: if a reviewer does this often, when the edit probably could have been accepted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but if one user does that often, or many reviewers do that sometime, for me it's the same thing. Because we have the same behaviour spread on 1/2/3k  or more users. But following your comment this shouldn't be reported.. so thank you so much for the clarification and the patience.